# Combining data frames into one data frame and keep empty data frame as NA

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

Here is my code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Intercept = .4, x1=.4, x2=.2, x3=.7)
df2 <- data.frame(Interceptlego = .5,x2=.8)
df3 <- data.frame()
myList <- list(df1, df2, df3)
do.call(rbind.fill, myList)
```

I wonder how can I rbind df3 into a single data frame as "NA"s?

I found an article from r_blogger about Combining vectors or data frames of unequal length into one data frame. http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-combining-vectors-or-data-frames-of-unequal-length-into-one-data-frame/

But the data frame I got from my data, some of them are empty which contains "<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)"

What I want to accomplish is like this

```
  Intercept  x1  x2  x3 Interceptlego
1       0.4 0.4 0.2 0.7            NA
2        NA  NA 0.8  NA           0.5
3        NA  NA NA   NA            NA
```

Comment: Well, put `NA` values in the empty data.frame to make sure that it contains what you expect? An empty data.frame is empty. Combining it with another data.frame shouldn't change the other data.frame.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Please see my update on what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really follow your logic. An empty data.frame doesn't contain any observations and should not result in a row after `rbind`ing.

Anyway, assuming you know a column name that occurs at least once:

```
myList <- lapply(myList, function(df) {
  if (!ncol(df)) df <- data.frame(Intercept = NA)
  df
})
library(data.table)
rbindlist(myList, fill = TRUE)
#   Intercept  x1  x2  x3 Interceptlego
#1:       0.4 0.4 0.2 0.7            NA
#2:        NA  NA 0.8  NA           0.5
#3:        NA  NA  NA  NA            NA
```

Use `setDF` subsequently if you prefer not having a data.table.

Comment: Thank you Roland. This is the problem actually I have. Since nobody answer it so I ask the question above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417159/rdstk-reverse-multiple-address-to-lat-lon-deal-with-0-rows-or-0-length-row-na